# Need advice for my Server part

Tags: sql-server, database, json, rest

I'm stuck on my server part.
I thing it would be fine if I make an REST architecture but I'm not sure.

My application is that an identitied user edit his name, age, hobbies...and I want to stock all the informations of all the users on my data server. Then, I could send the information of a user to another in a ListView with an adaptater.

Any idea to help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have recently added a series of posts to [my blog](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/) that may help.  It covers creating a RESTful service using Java EE technologies on the GlassFish server.  The example produces consumes XML, but could easily be adapted to handle JSON.

- [Part 1 - The Database Model](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-15.html)
- [Part 2 - Mapping the Database Model to JPA Entities](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-25.html)
- [Part 3 - Mapping JPA Entities to XML using JAXB](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-35.html)
- [Part 4 - The RESTful Service](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-45.html)